# how to select values from mongodb using mongoose

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i am using meanstack now i try to fetch the data from mongodb with the help of angularjs i am very new in this technology.i insert the values correctly now i want to retrieve from mongodb-mongoose

i am using meanstack now i try to fetch the data from mongodb with the help of angularjs i am very new in this technology.i insert the values correctly now i want to retrieve from mongodb-mongoose

```js
var app = angular.module("App", [ ]);

  
app.controller('MongooseController', ['$scope', '$http' ,'$window', '$filter',
 
 
function ($scope, $http, $window, $filter) {
      

    debugger;
    
    var refresh = function () {
        $http.get('/ViewUser').then(function (response) {
            $scope.ViewUsers = response.data;
        });
 
    };
    refresh();

    $scope.AddNewDetails = function ( ) {

        $http.post('/AddNewDetails', $scope.user).then(function (response) {
            

        });
    };
 

}]);









server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 


app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/crud');

var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    name: String,
    age: Number,
 

    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
   

});

var user = mongoose.model('emps', Schema);

app.get('/ViewUser', function (req, res) {

    user.find({}, function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
    });

});
 
app.post('/AddNewDetails', function (req, res) {

 
    new user({
        email: req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name,
        age: req.body.age
       


    }).save(function (err, doc) {

        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        else {
             
            res.send('Successfully inserted!');
        }
    });
});





app.listen(8082);
console.log("server running on port 8082");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Controller/MongooseCrud.js"></script>
</head>

<body >

    <div ng-controller="MongooseController">
  
     

        <label for="email">Email: </label>
   <input type="email" name="email"  ng-model="user.email" /><br />
 <label for="name">Name: </label>
   <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
 <label for="age">Age: </label>
   <input type="number" name="age" ng-model="user.age"/><br />
   <input type="Button"  value="submit" ng-click="AddNewDetails()">

        <ul ng-repeat="ViewUser in ViewUsers">
            <li>{{ViewUser.name}}</li>
        </ul>




    </div>
     


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be,

```
User.find({}, function(err, docs) {
 console.log(docs);
}
```

Also change your request as,

```
 $http.get('/ViewUser').then(function (response) {
            $scope.ViewUsers = response.data;
 });
```

Comment: what do you see

Comment: what do you see in the console?

Comment: console db values are shown but iam not able to get in  UI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139235/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-jose).

Comment: ANY MISTAKE @Sajeetharan

Comment: change it to
$scope.refresh = function () { 
$http.get('/ViewUser').then(function (response) { 
$scope.ViewUsers = response.data; 
}); 

};
and call it on ng-init

Comment: what happened witht the issue?

Comment: response.data is must?when i use mongojs i simply give response?